# Webscraping novels and paragraphs: Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all")

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, sapply

I'm trying to web scrape the entire works of an author (not in English) from this website: https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/

Basically, every chapter from his books is put in links at the right-hand side of the website. I'm using rvest from tidyverse and polite package because I'm just trying to be polite here. I load xml2 package as well in case the error has something to do with that.

First, I take all the chapter links like this. The chapter links already contain book titles, so I didn't need to scrape book titles. Being polite, I leave my email in the user_agent.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(polite)
library(xml2) 

link <- "https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/"
session <- bow(link, user_agent = "Hi, I'm webscraping for research"))

chapter_links <-  scrape(session) %>%
  html_nodes(".textwidget a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

It retrieves 901 links. Then I removed the first 3 and last 3 links because it's not chapter links

```
chapter_links <- chapter_links[4:898]
```

Then I try to scrape only one chapter using the first chapter link. I collapse it into one character vector. I'm not sure what verbose = TRUE does, I just follow the tutorial. I get the chapter that I wanted.

```
chapter_link <- "https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls-01/"
 chapter <- bow(chapter_link) %>% scrape(verbose = TRUE) %>%
   html_nodes("p") %>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
```

Next, I try to create a function that can scrape over the entire links

```
get_chapter <-  function(chapter_link) {
    chapter <- bow(chapter_link) %>% scrape(verbose = TRUE) %>%
    html_nodes("p") %>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
  return(chapter)
}
```

I try using sapply

```
text <- sapply(chapter_links, FUN = get_chapter)
```

And get the error message:
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") :
no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "NULL"

Where have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `rvest` instead of `polite`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

df <- tibble(links = "https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/" %>%
         read_html() %>%
         html_elements(".textwidget a") %>%
         html_attr("href") %>%
         .[4:898])

# A tibble: 895 x 1
   links                                                                         
   <chr>                                                                         
 1 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 2 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 3 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 4 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 5 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 6 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 7 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 8 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
 9 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
10 https://serialshmintardja.wordpress.com/pdls/pelangi-di-langit-singasari/pdls~
# ... with 885 more rows
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Scraping the first 10 links

```
df %>%  
  slice(1:10) %>% 
  mutate(content = map_chr(links, ~ .x %>%  
                             read_html() %>%  
                             html_elements("p") %>% 
                             html_text2() %>% 
                             paste(collapse = ", "))) %>% 
  relocate(content)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   content                                                                  links
   <chr>                                                                    <chr>
 1 ", Bagian I – Bunga di Kaki Gunung Kawi, HAMPIR BERSAMAAN KEDUANYA meng~ http~
 2 ", kembali | lanjut >>, , KARENA MAHISA AGNI masih tegak di pintu, berk~ http~
 3 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, , KEMUDIAN Agni merasa tangan-tangan yang ber~ http~
 4 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, , Mahisa Agni yang berlutut di muka ibunya it~ http~
 5 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, , SEKALI LAGI MAHISA AGNI MEMANDANGI AKAR WRE~ http~
 6 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, , MAHISA AGNI PUN KEMUDIAN membenahi diri. Me~ http~
 7 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, , PRAJURIT KAWAN KEBO IJO itu tertawa. Ketika~ http~
 8 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, , MAHISA AGNI DAPAT MENGERTI SELURUHNYA. Kare~ http~
 9 ", <<kembali | lanjut >>, NAMUN KETIKA IA MENDENGAR JAWABAN Ki Buyut Pa~ http~
10 ", << kembali | lanjut >>, DAKSINA BERJALAN PERLAHAN-LAHAN MENDEKATI pi~ http~
```

Comment: What does html_text2() for? It works but if I don't slice it and run over all the links, there is HTTP error 400. Maybe some link works and some don't.

Comment: `html_text2()` fetches the text as you see it on the website, parses the html objects etc. Yeah, you will probably encounter that error since youre trying to scrape 900 sites. The website is going to reject it at some point. Slice it bulk and append together is probably your best option. Alternatively, at a `sys.sleep` and incorporate `tryCatch` in the code.